# How to split a string after all uppercase words using a delimiter in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, delimiter

I'm trying to parse this string as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_1 (a1 int, a2 varchar(20));
```

To:

```
CREATE TABLE 

tbl_1 (a1 int, a2 varchar(20));
```

How would I go about doing this with a delimiter in Java?

I am able to parse:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_1;
```

To:

```
CREATE DATABASE 

db_1;
```

with this code but it doesn't work for the statement at the beginning of the post.

```
public static void read()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("-->");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    String [] num = new String[10];
    Scanner parse = new Scanner(input);
    parse.useDelimiter("\s((?=[a-z][a-z]))");
    
    int i = 0;
    while (parse.hasNext())
    {
        num[i] = parse.next();
        System.out.println("Output " + i + " is: " + num[i]);
        
        if(num[i].contains("CREATE DATABASE"))
        {
            System.out.println("YOOOOOOO");
            
        }
        
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done properly using a different approach, but using your approach of a scanner delimiter:

```
parse.useDelimiter("(?<=[A-Z])\\s");
```

This splits on spaces that are preceded by a capital letter.

Not *exactly* correct in all cases, but should work well for your case of parsing SHOUTED KEYWORDS formatted SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to this regEx:

```
parse.useDelimiter("(?=tbl)");
```

You can pass whatever delimiter you want too, with:

```
String delimiter = "tbl";
parse.useDelimiter("(?="+delimit+")");
```

This find the first occurrence of a whitespace before the `String` you want.